# Fast way to determine which datapoints lay above a predefined multisegmented line?

Tags: r, mapply

I need to scan nearly a million datapoints and determine if they lay under or above a threshold. I have the threshold defined globally and I have a simple predefined function

```
function.lower.penalty <- function(i,j){   if( i < j ){
    #if gate condition is met, flip the gate flag:
    n <- 1   }else{n<-0}   return(n) }
```

that I call with mapply, which will write a 0/1 flag column in my dataframe:

```
df[, paste0("outside.highpass")]  <- mapply(function.lower.penalty,i="somesignal.found.in.df", j="*some.threshold.found.in.df*"  )
```

This is pretty straightforward, I can flag dozens of signals with their respective thresholds like this in a second big dataframe. Also, given how the threshold is written, the code will either flag the signals as below/above the threshold (meaning I got also a function.higher.penalty).

Now I was asked to make a more complex threshold that has the shape of a multisegmented line.
What is the fastest way to flag datapoints given that you have only the corner points of the multisegmented line (I can guess them according to how they painted the line) visible [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lgv0r.jpg).

Until now I had a predefined threshold (gray 0.2) and used mapply to scan the signal drawn on the x-axis. I just used a function to return 0 or 1 if datapoint was smaller or bigger than the threshold. Now I need a multisegmented line like the one drawn in red to do the same job.

Edit: Using the suggestion from det I was able to flag datapoints in the dataframe. However, it seems that some datapoints close to the defined line are wrongly assinged, see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNgfQ.jpg). I am wondering as how to work around it or if this is a drawing error?

Answer (score 1):

You can create function which returns picewise linear function based on  points:

```
picewiseLinear <- function(x.var, y.var){
  
  stopifnot(length(x.var) == length(y.var), sum(duplicated(x.var)) == 0)
  
  p <- order(x.var)
  x.var <- x.var[p]
  y.var <- y.var[p]
  
  k <- diff(y.var) / diff(x.var)
  l <- -1 * k * head(x.var, -1) + head(y.var, -1)
  
  function(x){
    
    ind <- findInterval(x, x.var)
    if(!all(between(ind, 1, length(x.var) - 1))) stop("wrong input")
    
    x * k[ind] + l[ind]
  }
}
```

For example:

```
point_df <- tribble(
  ~x, ~y,
  3,  0,
  5,  2,
  3,  3,
  5,  4
)

f <- picewiseLinear(point_df$y, point_df$x)
```

(on your picture you have picewise linear function but looked on x as dependent variable)

and on example dataset you get something like this:

```
set.seed(123)
tibble(
  x = runif(1000, 0, 6),
  y = runif(1000, 0, 4)
) %>%
  mutate(color = ifelse(x > f(y), "red", "blue")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_point(aes(color = color)) +
    scale_color_identity() +
    geom_path(data = point_df)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for that answer! I managed to adapt it and instead of coloring, I create a column with the according subset number. However, if I plot then the two subsets I realized that some points close to the multisegemented line are seemingly wrongly flagged. See the picture I added in my EDIT. I am not sure if this is a drawing error though.

Comment: might have with the fact that you have logaritmic scale on plots. Try to do with normal scale (subset data on those regions if needed for better inspection)

Comment: I need to adapt this code once again to include the possibily to have the picewiseLinear acting on y as the dependent variable. First I thought I might just swap the x.var for y.var but this of course does not work. Do you have the function at hand for the coordinate flipped? thank you so much in advance!

Comment: `y.var` is dependent variable

Comment: what I mean is a piecewise tibble that has unique x points and unique y coordinates. just an ordinary function y = f(y). just swapping picewiseLinear(point_df$y, point_df$x) to picewiseLinear(point_df$x, point_df$y) gives me wrongly assigned data points. I cannot post a picture since the answer got deleted.

Comment: You should provide example because I don't understand what you want. `f(y)=y` is equation for fixed points of function `f`.